# Browser isn't recognize local path from img tag HTML

Tags: html

I have problems with img tag in HTML. I try to use relative path and absolute image file path like this:

```
<img src="../../images/pages/404-page/bg-construct-image.jpg"/>
<img src="D:\Web_HomeOWN\images\pages\404-page\bg-construct-image.jpg"/>
```

But this image didn't display. When I inspect img element with firefox and I try to click at the image path. 
Then I got this path: `file:///images/pages/404-page/bg-construct-image.jpg`
The right path would be like this: `file:///D:/Web_HomeOWN/images/pages/404-page/bg-construct-image.jpg`

My local image path: `D:\Web_HomeOWN\images\pages\404-page\bg-construct-image.jpg`
My local html path: `D:\Web_HomeOWN\Index.html`
[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQElW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your structure, you don't need to navigate **up** two folders, as your `index.html` is already in `Web_HomeOWN`. Simply referencing `<img src="images/pages/404-page/bg-construct-image.jpg"/>` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh my, this is so basic. Because I use this script to separately load header, footer, and content into Index page.
  $("header").load("views/home/header.html");
    $("footer").load("views/home/footer.html");
    $("main").load("views/pages/masonry-gallery.html"); 
Then I forgot that I must navigate from Index not from content page. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`../` is used to come backward from the location of html file. In your case image file is actually located in sub-directory of your html file, So you need not to use `../`. You can use img as follows.

```
<img src="images/pages/404-page/bg-construct-image.jpg"/>
```